# Corrupt video file - HEX trails off to zeroes

Tags: video

Have an mp4 mov file that is 3.32GB and should be 5+ min long. Filmed with GH4 cam. The file is on the computer and the SD card cannot be restored because it was formatted and used about 20 times after. The file plays fine for about 17 seconds and then stops. As you can see in the attached screenshot, the HEX shows good data until line 0EC00000, which is very close to the beginning (probably the good 17 seconds). After that, and all the way to end of the file - there are only ZEROS. Does this mean that there is NO data to fix? Is the last 4.5 minutes lost forever?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your only hope is a file system recovery program.  i.e. you're hoping the full file still exists on the SD somewhere.
Note formatting generally does NOT remove all possibility of recovering files, in simple terms it just tells the system it can use all this space, it doesn't physically clear every byte.  continued usage of the SD will decrease the chances of recovery, esp with large files like movies.

Here is one such utility: [EaseUS](http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/card-recovery-software/sd-card-recovery-freeware.htm)

You can't 'recreate' the missing data, you've no information left to base it on...